# Kernel Mode: BSOD to obtain image base of win32k.sys module

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, driver, kernel-module

The code below is able to enumerate several kernel modules and get some info from them correctly. I use `MyEnumKernelModule` method to get base address of a determinate module and from this, obtain image base of this module. But i have a **BSOD** in `ImgBase` method when i try search by **win32k.sys** (to any other module works 100%). Below `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS` is used to obtain image base.

Why this trouble?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <ntimage.h>
#include <WinDef.h>

typedef enum _SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS 
{
    SystemBasicInformation = 0,
    SystemProcessorInformation = 1,             
    SystemPerformanceInformation = 2,
    SystemTimeOfDayInformation = 3,
    SystemPathInformation = 4,
    SystemProcessInformation = 5,
    SystemCallCountInformation = 6,
    SystemDeviceInformation = 7,
    SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation = 8,
    SystemFlagsInformation = 9,
    SystemCallTimeInformation = 10,
    SystemModuleInformation = 11,
    SystemLocksInformation = 12,
    SystemStackTraceInformation = 13,
    SystemPagedPoolInformation = 14,
    SystemNonPagedPoolInformation = 15,
    SystemHandleInformation = 16,
    SystemObjectInformation = 17,
    SystemPageFileInformation = 18,
    SystemVdmInstemulInformation = 19,
    SystemVdmBopInformation = 20,
    SystemFileCacheInformation = 21,
    SystemPoolTagInformation = 22,
    SystemInterruptInformation = 23,
    SystemDpcBehaviorInformation = 24,
    SystemFullMemoryInformation = 25,
    SystemLoadGdiDriverInformation = 26,
    SystemUnloadGdiDriverInformation = 27,
    SystemTimeAdjustmentInformation = 28,
    SystemSummaryMemoryInformation = 29,
    SystemMirrorMemoryInformation = 30,
    SystemPerformanceTraceInformation = 31,
    SystemObsolete0 = 32,
    SystemExceptionInformation = 33,
    SystemCrashDumpStateInformation = 34,
    SystemKernelDebuggerInformation = 35,
    SystemContextSwitchInformation = 36,
    SystemRegistryQuotaInformation = 37,
    SystemExtendServiceTableInformation = 38,
    SystemPrioritySeperation = 39,
    SystemVerifierAddDriverInformation = 40,
    SystemVerifierRemoveDriverInformation = 41,
    SystemProcessorIdleInformation = 42,
    SystemLegacyDriverInformation = 43,
    SystemCurrentTimeZoneInformation = 44,
    SystemLookasideInformation = 45,
    SystemTimeSlipNotification = 46,
    SystemSessionCreate = 47,
    SystemSessionDetach = 48,
    SystemSessionInformation = 49,
    SystemRangeStartInformation = 50,
    SystemVerifierInformation = 51,
    SystemVerifierThunkExtend = 52,
    SystemSessionProcessInformation = 53,
    SystemLoadGdiDriverInSystemSpace = 54,
    SystemNumaProcessorMap = 55,
    SystemPrefetcherInformation = 56,
    SystemExtendedProcessInformation = 57,
    SystemRecommendedSharedDataAlignment = 58,
    SystemComPlusPackage = 59,
    SystemNumaAvailableMemory = 60,
    SystemProcessorPowerInformation = 61,
    SystemEmulationBasicInformation = 62,
    SystemEmulationProcessorInformation = 63,
    SystemExtendedHandleInformation = 64,
    SystemLostDelayedWriteInformation = 65,
    SystemBigPoolInformation = 66,
    SystemSessionPoolTagInformation = 67,
    SystemSessionMappedViewInformation = 68,
    SystemHotpatchInformation = 69,
    SystemObjectSecurityMode = 70,
    SystemWatchdogTimerHandler = 71,
    SystemWatchdogTimerInformation = 72,
    SystemLogicalProcessorInformation = 73,
    SystemWow64SharedInformation = 74,
    SystemRegisterFirmwareTableInformationHandler = 75,
    SystemFirmwareTableInformation = 76,
    SystemModuleInformationEx = 77,
    SystemVerifierTriageInformation = 78,
    SystemSuperfetchInformation = 79,
    SystemMemoryListInformation = 80,
    SystemFileCacheInformationEx = 81,
    MaxSystemInfoClass = 82  

} SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS;

extern "C" NTSTATUS ZwQuerySystemInformation(
IN UINT SystemInformationClass,
IN OUT PVOID SystemInformation,
IN ULONG SystemInformationLength,
OUT PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL ) ;

typedef struct {
    PVOID   Unknown1;
    PVOID   Unknown2;
    PVOID   Base;
    ULONG   Size;
    ULONG   Flags;
    USHORT  Index;
    USHORT  NameLength;
    USHORT  LoadCount;
    USHORT  PathLength;
    CHAR    ImageName[256];
} SYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION_ENTRY, *PSYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION_ENTRY;

NTSTATUS MyEnumKernelModule(IN CHAR* str, OUT PVOID *moduleadd)
{
NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
ULONG n = 0;
ULONG i = 0;
PSYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION_ENTRY module = NULL;
PVOID pbuftmp = NULL;
ANSI_STRING ModuleName1,ModuleName2;

status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation, &n, 0, &n);

pbuftmp = ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, n);

status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation, pbuftmp, n, NULL);
module = (PSYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION_ENTRY)((PULONG )pbuftmp + 1 );

RtlInitAnsiString(&ModuleName1,str);

n = *((PULONG)pbuftmp );
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
RtlInitAnsiString(&ModuleName2, module[i].ImageName);
DbgPrint("%d 0x%08X 0x%08X %s \n",module[i].Index, module[i].Base,module[i].Size,module[i].ImageName);
if (RtlCompareString(&ModuleName1, &ModuleName2, TRUE) == 0)
{
DbgPrint("\n Found!\n Path: %s \n BaseAddr: 0x%08X \n\n", ModuleName2.Buffer, module[i].Base);
*moduleadd = module[i].Base;
break;
}
}
ExFreePool(pbuftmp);

return status;
}

VOID ImgBase(IN PVOID lpBase, OUT PULONG pImageBase) {

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpBase;
    if (pDosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        DbgPrint("Image has no DOS header!\n");
        return;
    }
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNtHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((char *)lpBase + pDosHeader->e_lfanew);
    if (pNtHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        DbgPrint("Image has no NT header!\n");
        return;
    }
    if (pImageBase)
        *pImageBase = pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING  RegistryPath);
#endif

void testUnload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    DbgPrint("Goodbye from test!\n");
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING  RegistryPath)
{
    ULONG uImageBase = 0;
    PVOID ModuleAddress = NULL;

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = testUnload;

    DbgPrint("Hello from test!\n");

    MyEnumKernelModule("\\systemroot\\system32\\win32k.sys",&ModuleAddress);
//  DbgPrint("ModuleAddress: 0x%08X \n", ModuleAddress);
    ImgBase(ModuleAddress, &uImageBase);
    DbgPrint("ImageBase: 0x%08X", uImageBase); 

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: *win32k.sys* mapped in session space. in not mapped in system process address space. you and must got bsod if try access it base from system process

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157701/discussion-on-question-by-joao-pablo-kernel-mode-bsod-to-obtain-image-base-of-w).