# How list all modules of system (not modules of my own process)?

Tags: c++, winapi, enumeration, kernel-module

I want list all modules of system. Have a code that list only all modules loaded in my own process. So, how change the following code for turn able of enumerate all modules of system (including **ntoskrnl.exe** and **win32k.sys**)? thank you.

## ====================

## ====================

## ====================

====================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib")

typedef struct _RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION
{
    HANDLE Section;
    PVOID MappedBase;
    PVOID ImageBase;
    ULONG ImageSize;
    ULONG Flags;
    USHORT LoadOrderIndex;
    USHORT InitOrderIndex;
    USHORT LoadCount;
    USHORT OffsetToFileName;
    UCHAR FullPathName[256];
} RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION, *PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _RTL_PROCESS_MODULES
{
    ULONG NumberOfModules;
    RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION Modules[1];
} RTL_PROCESS_MODULES, *PRTL_PROCESS_MODULES;

int main()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG i;

    PRTL_PROCESS_MODULES ModuleInfo;

    ModuleInfo=(PRTL_PROCESS_MODULES)VirtualAlloc(NULL,1024*1024,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_READWRITE); // Allocate memory for the module list

    if(!ModuleInfo)
    {
        printf("\nUnable to allocate memory for module list (%d)\n",GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if(!NT_SUCCESS(status=NtQuerySystemInformation((SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS)11,ModuleInfo,1024*1024,NULL))) // 11 = SystemModuleInformation
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to query module list (%#x)\n",status);

        VirtualFree(ModuleInfo,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<ModuleInfo->NumberOfModules;i++)
    {
        printf("\n*****************************************************\n");
        printf("\nImage base: %#x\n",ModuleInfo->Modules[i].ImageBase);
        printf("\nImage name: %s\n",ModuleInfo->Modules[i].FullPathName+ModuleInfo->Modules[i].OffsetToFileName);
        printf("\nImage full path: %s\n",ModuleInfo->Modules[i].FullPathName);
        printf("\nImage size: %d\n",ModuleInfo->Modules[i].ImageSize);
        printf("\n*****************************************************\n");
    }

    VirtualFree(ModuleInfo,0,MEM_RELEASE);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Produce a succinct specification for what *"all modules of [the] system"* means, and convert it to code. We don't know what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: `"\nImage base: %#x\n"` - `%#x` is your error. use `%p` format here

Comment: @RbMm, relative to my last comment on previous post, my code usermode (that finds correctly iimage base address) that returns image base of *win32k.sys* is in Delphi (Pascal). Then i wants make the same thing here in C++ (usermode) to compare image base values (C++: usermode and kernel mode) respectivally) to try find why kernel code returns wrong address of *win32k.sys* on Win 8.1 and highter).

Comment: Only not works in Win 8.1 and highter. Very strange.

Comment: @JoãoPablo - only by some mistake in your code. my code perfect work from xp to win10

Comment: @RbMm, sincerelly i don't know where is error, once that works fine until Win 8. You saw on screenshot in my [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961637/kernel-mode-bsod-to-obtain-image-base-of-win32k-sys-module?noredirect=1#comment80879516_46961637) of my previous question that base address is ok! but image base address already is different of **0x00010000** :-(

Comment: You could point on code of my previous question (if possible indentify) where i'm making wrong please?

Comment: @JoãoPablo - are you fix `%#x` ? are you not wow process ?

Comment: @RbMm, yes. But still i'm getting the list of module only of my own process.

Comment: @JoãoPablo - *only of my own process* - what you mean ? this code must list kernel drivers.

Comment: @RbMm, i also think this. This is a usermode code. List only dlls files (and only of my own process).

Comment: @JoãoPablo - user mode - and so what ?? why when i write this code all perfect worked ?

Comment: @RbMm, to say true, this code above not list modules of my own process but list **only some dll files** of system. Not list *.sys, *.exe files. If you test you will see.

Comment: this can not be. for me al work ok. i test and all work. paste your binary file

Comment: @RbMm, [here is](https://www.sendspace.com/file/hnyrgi) compiled file.

Comment: your exe print all kernel drivers. what you want ?

Comment: @RbMm, ok. Now [see it](http://prntscr.com/h2uc8c). This is what happens here :-(. The first module should be **ntoskrnl.exe** right?

Comment: @JoãoPablo - you simply set too small console buffer size. you lost first records

Comment: @RbMm, Then what must be right size of buffer?

Comment: @JoãoPablo - first of all you need be able to use debugger. know how output results. are you know how change console screen buffer size in menu ? in what problem. i already nothing say about your hard-code buffer size in code (this is absolute different) and very not optimized loop

Comment: @RbMm, yes solved! I used `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Workable code. Lib https://github.com/winsiderss/systeminformer

```
#define PHNT_VERSION PHNT_WIN11_23H2
#define WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH
#include <phnt_windows.h>
#include <phnt.h>
#include <string>
#include "ntmmapi.h"


int main()
{
    NTSTATUS             Status = 0;
    PRTL_PROCESS_MODULES ModulesInfo;
    ULONG                SysModuleInfoBufferSize = 0;
    std::string               SearchModuleString;
    //
    // Get required size of "RTL_PROCESS_MODULES" buffer
    //
    Status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation, NULL, NULL, &SysModuleInfoBufferSize);
    ModulesInfo = (PRTL_PROCESS_MODULES)VirtualAlloc(
        NULL,
        SysModuleInfoBufferSize,
        MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (!ModulesInfo)
    {
        printf("err, unable to allocate memory for module list (%x)\n",
            GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    Status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemModuleInformation,
        ModulesInfo,
        SysModuleInfoBufferSize,
        NULL);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    {
        printf("err, unable to query module list (%x)\n", Status);

        VirtualFree(ModulesInfo, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return FALSE;
    }

    printf("kernel mode\n");
    printf("start\t\t\tsize\tname\t\t\t\tpath\n\n");

    for (ULONG i = 0; i < ModulesInfo->NumberOfModules; i++)
    {
        RTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION* CurrentModule = &ModulesInfo->Modules[i];
        /* TODO: List of all sections of modules
        // Open the section object for the module
        HANDLE hSection = CurrentModule->Section;
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objAttr;
        InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttr, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        NTSTATUS status = NtOpenSection(&hSection, SECTION_QUERY, &objAttr);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            // Query the section object information
            SECTION_BASIC_INFORMATION sectionInfo;
            status = NtQuerySection(hSection, SectionBasicInformation, &sectionInfo, sizeof(sectionInfo), NULL);
            if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
            {
                // Print the section's address
                printf("Section address: %p\n", sectionInfo.BaseAddress); 
            }

            // Close the section object
            NtClose(hSection);
        }*/

        printf("%p\t", CurrentModule->ImageBase);
        printf("%x\t", CurrentModule->ImageSize);

        auto   PathName = CurrentModule->FullPathName + CurrentModule->OffsetToFileName;
        UINT32 PathNameLen = strlen((const char*)PathName);

        printf("%s\t", PathName);

        if (PathNameLen >= 24)
        {
        }
        else if (PathNameLen >= 16)
        {
            printf("\t");
        }
        else if (PathNameLen >= 8)
        {
            printf("\t\t");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t\t\t");
        }

        printf("%s\n", CurrentModule->FullPathName);
    }

    VirtualFree(ModulesInfo, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: An answer must explain the issue and how the proposed solution addresses it.